# Converting a nonstandard US datetime string to datetime in SQL

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012

I have a dataset with dates in the format as follows:

```
10/18/2007   8:00 A.M.

10/20/2007  10:00 A.M.
```

etc..

I'm having a lot of trouble finding a consistent query to convert a set of varchars in this format to datetime for insertion into a datetime column.  I have tried many of the CONVERT styles (found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) but none really works.

Comment: What conversions have you attempted? just saying *many* isn't really that helpful. Which?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sql Server 2012 and up: each of these will return `null` when the conversion fails instead of an error.

- [**`try_convert(datatype,val)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx)
- [**`try_cast(val as datatype)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974669.aspx)
- [**`try_parse(val as datatype [using culture])`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx)

---

```
declare @str varchar(32) = '10/20/2007  10:00 A.M.'
select try_parse(replace(@str,'.M.','M') as datetime using 'EN-us')
```

returns: `2007-10-20 10:00:00`

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/KWCF9843

Answer (score 1):

You just need to strip the periods out and then simply convert

```
Select try_convert(datetime,replace('10/18/2007  8:00 A.M.','.',''))
```

Returns

```
2007-10-18 08:00:00.000
```